# inner join on multiple columns return duplicate records

Tags: mysql

I have table say **abc**

```
id smownerid    smcreatorid
1  33997         1
2  33997         1
3  33997         1
4  33998         1
5  33998         1
6  33998         33998
7  33998         33998
8  33998         33998
9  33998         33998
10 33940         33998
11 33940         33998
12 3             33998
13 33940         1
14 33940         33998
15 33997         33997
16 3             33997
17 33940         33998
18 4             33940
19 4             33997
20 33980        33940
```

Another table **non_admin_users**

```
id
3
33940
33997
33998
33999
```

My Sql query is

```
SELECT abc.* from abc
INNER JOIN non_admin_users vt_tmp_u33998 ON vt_tmp_u33998.id = abc.smownerid
OR (
vt_tmp_u33998.id = abc.smcreatorid
AND vt_tmp_u33998.id =33998
)
```

This query return duplicate records.

What I want is to fetch all the records from abc table whose smownerid equal to the non_admin_users' id or whose smcreatorid is 33998 without using where clause or distinct id column or group by statement.

I want this following output

```
id smownerid    smcreatorid
1  33997         1
2  33997         1
3  33997         1
4  33998         1
5  33998         1
6  33998         33998
7  33998         33998
8  33998         33998
9  33998         33998
10 33940         33998
11 33940         33998
12 3             33998
13 33940         1
14 33940         33998
15 33997         33997
16 3             33997
17 33940         33998
```

Comment: It's a bit confusing that your query refers to a table not quoted in the question (vtiger_crmentit)  and why the tricky alias for non-admin_users?

Comment: Sorry for the query. join for non_admin_users is neccessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INNER JOIN non_admin_users vt_tmp_u33998 ON ( vt_tmp_u33998.id = abc.smownerid AND abc.smcreatorid !=33998 ) OR (vt_tmp_u33998.id = abc.smcreatorid AND vt_tmp_u33998.id =33998)
```

Comment: I got confused with smcreatorid=33998. If you only have mentioned on_admin_users.id=33998 instead of smcreatorid then it would be a lot easier. I thought abc table can have records that do not exists in on_admin_users table and I believe all of us who posted an answer have similar thought on your concern that is why all the posted codes were focusing on the field smcreator from abc table otherwise they could have just do a plain select and join without a sub queries like what you did. I could be wrong thou

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.smownerid, a.smcreatorid
FROM abc a JOIN non_admin_users na ON a.smownerid = na.id
WHERE a.smownerid = 33998;
```

You can comment out `WHERE` condition if you want all the records.

Comment: I want is to fetch all the records from abc table whose **smownerid** equal to the non_admin_users's **id** or smcreator is equal to 33998.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try?

```
SELECT a.*
FROM abc a LEFT JOIN non_admin_users na ON a.smownerid = na.id
WHERE a.smcreatorid = 33998 OR IFNULL(na.id,'') != '';
```

[OR] Just to make sure that 33998 records won't be joined twice.

```
select * from 
(SELECT a.*
FROM abc a INNER JOIN non_admin_users na ON a.smownerid = na.id AND a.smcreatorid!=33998
UNION ALL
SELECT b.* FROM abc b INNER JOIN abc b1 ON b.id=b1.id AND b.smcreatorid=33998) a
order by id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps an implicit distinct in a union is ok

```
select  * from
(
SELECT a.id, A.smownerid, A.smcreatorid 
FROM ABC  a
INNER JOIN non_admin_users n on n.id = a.smownerid and a.smcreatorid <> 33998
union 
SELECT a.id, A.smownerid, A.smcreatorid 
FROM ABC  a
inner JOIN non_admin_users n on n.id = a.smownerid 
) s 
order by id
;

+------+-----------+-------------+
| id   | smownerid | smcreatorid |
+------+-----------+-------------+
|    1 |     33997 |           1 |
|    2 |     33997 |           1 |
|    3 |     33997 |           1 |
|    4 |     33998 |           1 |
|    5 |     33998 |           1 |
|    6 |     33998 |       33998 |
|    7 |     33998 |       33998 |
|    8 |     33998 |       33998 |
|    9 |     33998 |       33998 |
|   10 |     33940 |       33998 |
|   11 |     33940 |       33998 |
|   12 |         3 |       33998 |
|   13 |     33940 |           1 |
|   14 |     33940 |       33998 |
|   15 |     33997 |       33997 |
|   16 |         3 |       33997 |
|   17 |     33940 |       33998 |
+------+-----------+-------------+
```

Comment: There should be Lakh of record in ABC Table. union will slow down preformance. @P.Salmon